# Is there any workaround to fix unbalanced quotes in CSV file while loading into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, export-to-csv, google-cloud-sql

I got CSV files from Cloud SQL to Cloud Storage and trying to load them into BigQuery. Found that files are having unbalanced quotes instead of NULL values. For e.g. "N

Table Header: Name Updated_Time

Sample row in CSV: "ABC","N

```
bq load  --source_format=CSV --null_marker="\"N" --quote='"'
project_name:dataset_name.table_name gs://bucket_name/folder_name/*
```

Getting this error:
CSV table references column position
1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 column.

Comment: Did you try with --null_marker='"N' (use simple quote and not escape double quote) ?

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Is it not possible to pre process the files?

Comment: It seems that is not getting the number of columns right, have you tried adding `--autodetect` or even specifying the table schema like `qtr:STRING,sales:FLOAT,year:STRING`? There are some samples [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)

Comment: --autodetect also didn't work. As a workaround I am trying to insert into a staging table with quotes and load into final table excluding quotes.

Comment: It will be my ultimate solutions. Either you can perform a pre processing before the bqload, or you perform it after with a request (be careful of data size and cost). Additional tips: you can use UDF JavaScript in your query if you want for processing the fields. The execution time is slower than SQL but, for many people, it's easier to write.